# NetBeans -Djava.library.path separator differs in Windows and OS X

Tags: java, netbeans, separator, native-code, library-path

## About

I am having a NetBeans project with source code that includes two .jar files that load platform and architecture dependent native libraries each. The following shows the library structure in a generic way:

```
lib (NetBeans project root level)
  MyLib
    lib1-osx
    lib1-win
    lib2-osx
    lib2-win-x64
    lib1.jar
    lib2.jar
```

The paths of the native libraries need to be defined in the `-Djava.library.path` variable. The `VM Options` field within the `Run` property of the project properties looks like this for the generic library structure:

```
-Djava.library.path=
"./lib/MyLib/lib1-win";
"./lib/MyLib/lib1-osx";
"./lib/MyLib/lib2-win-x64";
"./lib/MyLib/lib2-osx";
```

## Problem

The string above only works for Windows because there the entries of `-Djava.library.path` are separated with `;` while OS X needs `:`.

## Question

Is there something like a placeholder where NetBeans inserts the correct separator for each OS? Otherwise I have to provide two different NetBeans projects what is definitely not what I want.

Comment: **No**. The separator is different between platforms, and there is no place holder to use instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So NetBeans is simply not made for something like "multi-os" projects?

Comment: Sure it is. But run-time configuration is not the same as "multi-os" project, run-time configuration is specific to a *run-time*.

Comment: Why would you have OSX library directories in a Windiws library path?

Comment: Because I simply wanted to have one VM Option string that can be used on any OS without having to switch the project configuration. Currently it is split up into a Windows and an OS X configuration that only contain paths to the libraries needed.